# Network driver for ubuntu 12.04 installed on Dell inspiron 14 R 5420

Tags: 12.04, networking, drivers, dell

I am new to ubuntu. I installed ubuntu 12.04 on my Dell Inspiron 14R 5420 and I am not being able to connect to internet because the network drivers. Please help me in finding and installing the drivers.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Can you find specs for your 14R? That may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you might need Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver

You first need to connect your laptop to the router with Ethernet cable in order to get internet access for downloading the necessary drivers. Then follow the steps below.

1. Open System Settings from the Launch Bar.
2. Click on Software Sources
3. Click on Additional Drivers tab
4. Select Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary)
5. Click on Apply Changes
6. Restart your laptop.
7. Set-up your wireless after logging in.